# presentation of the inertia group of $p$-adic fields

Tags: reference-request, galois-theory, p-adic-number-theory, group-presentation

It is known (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13733/wild-ramification/13743#13743)) that the absolute Galois group of a $p$-adic number field $K$ (ie a finite extension of $\mathbb Q_p$) is topologically finitely presented for any odd prime $p$.

Is it also true of the inertia subgroup, $\operatorname{Gal}(\bar K/K^{\rm unr})$, where $\bar K$ is the algebraic closure of $K$ and $K^\rm{unr}$ its maximal unramified extension ?

I know that the presentation cited in the above reference is explicit (so I could check if a lift of the Frobenius automorphism is given as one of the generators, and in that case it would be enough to omit it), but I don't know enough German (in which the original paper is written) to understand it.

I would be thankful for any given reference.